# Exclamation operator?

Tags: operators, d

I'm learning D and have seen a lot of code like this:

```
ushort x = to!ushort(args[1]);
```

I assume this casts `args[1]` to `ushort`, but what's the difference between this and `cast(ushort)`?

EDIT: And what other uses does the exclamation mark operator have?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In D,

```
to!ushort(args[1])
```

is shorthand for the **template instantiation**

```
to!(ushort)(args[1])
```

and is similar to

```
to<ushort>(args[1])
```

in languages like C++/Java/C#.

The exclamation point is to note the fact that it's not a regular argument, but a template argument.

The notation does *not* use angle brackets because those are *ridiculously* difficult to parse correctly for a compiler (they make the grammar very context-sensitive), which makes it that much more difficult to implement a correct compiler. See [here](http://www.d-programming-language.org/template-comparison.html) for more info.

The only other use I know about is just the unary 'not' operation (e.g. `false == !true`)... I can't think of any other uses at the moment.

---

Regarding the cast:

`cast(ushort)` is an *unchecked* cast, so it won't throw an exception if the value is out of range.

`to!ushort()` is a *checked* cast, so it throws an exception if the value is out of range.

Comment: It seems also that to! is more of a lexical cast, for example to!string(f) is valid for floating point f and cast(string)f - not.

Comment: I would point out that technically speaking `to!ushort(val)` is not actually a cast. It's a conversion using the function `std.conv.to`. It _is_ checked, but if you start calling it a cast, you risk causing confusion. Casting is only done with the cast operator.

Comment: @ Михаил Страшун That's because `std.conv.to` does a lot more than check that casts are valid before it does them. It deals with conversions in general. `std.conv.to` is a general conversion function and is extremely flexible.

Answer (score 3):

The exclamation mark here is not an operator, it is just a token part of the explicit template instantiation syntax (described in detail [here](http://dlang.org/template.html)).

`std.conv.to` ([docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#to)) is a function template for converting between arbitrary types. It is implemented entirely in the library and has no special support in the language. It has a broader and different scope compared to the cast operator.

The `to` template takes two type parameters; a "to" type and a "from" type, in that order. In your example, the template is explicitly instantiated with the single type argument `ushort` for the "to" parameter, and a second type argument `string` (assuming `args` comes from the first parameter to `main`) is automatically inferred from the regular function argument passed to the function (`args[1]`) as the "from" parameter.

The resulting function takes a string parameter and returns a ushort parsed from that string, or throws an exception if it failed. The cast operator will not attempt this kind of high-level conversion.

Note that if there is more than one explicit template parameter, or that parameter has more than one token in it (`ushort` is a single keyword token), you must wrap the template parameter list in parentheses:

```
ushort result;
result = to!(typeof(result))(args[1]);
```

In this example, `typeof`, `(`, `result` and `)` are four separate tokens and the parentheses are thus required.

To answer your last question, the `!` token is also used for the unary not operator, unrelated to template instantiations:

```
bool yes = true;
bool no = !yes; // 'no' is false
```

Answer (score 3):

You already got two excellent answers by jA_cOp and Merhdad. I just want answer directly to the OP question (*what's the difference between this and cast(ushort)?*) - The difference is that `cast(ushort)args[1]` will not work (you cannot cast from a string to an uint just like that), while the `to!(type)(param)` template knows what to do with the string and how to convert it to the primitive type.